# How to fetch specific fields of a sub-document population in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a User Model and Post Model as described below(required library imported)

**User Schema**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    post: [ mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'posts' ]
});
```

**Post Schema**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    postedOn: Date
});
```

I want to fetch post with respect to a user's id. But I don't want the whole Post document in return. I only want the attribute "Title" and "Date"
I tried the command:-

```
const posts = await User.findById(user_id).populate('post');
```

But it returns the entire collection. Can anyone tell me how can I fetch only "Title" and "Date" attribute of the post(sub-document) from User Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose population allows specific [field selection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection) by passing the usual [field name syntax](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

```
const posts = await User.findById(user_id).populate('post', 'Title Date');
```